# How to call a method which is defined inside a class from another class.

Tags: python-2.7

I have two classes here, TDUtility and CreateMAPInConfig. I want to use the method "enable_logons" inside "drop_map" method. How can I do it?

class TDUtility(object):

```
def __init__(self,system,path):

    self.__host = system
    self.__LogDIR__ = path

def enable_logons(self, ena_logons_log):

    cmd = "/usr/bin/tdsh -l root "+self.__host+" 'echo 'enable logons' | /usr/pde/bin/cnscons'"
```

class CreateMAPInConfig(object):

```
def __init__(self,system,path):

    self.__host = system
    self.__LogDIR__ = path  

def drop_map(self, auto_select, map_name):

    TDUtility().enable_logons("enable_logs3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your definition of drop_map, you have to specify a system and a path. If they are the ones from your CreateMAPInConfig, the code should look like this for 'drop_map':

```
TDUtility(self.__host, self.__LogDIR__).enable_logons("enable_logs3")
```

Comment: yes it will work, but it will reinitialize the variables in the TDUtility with the new values which I don't want. Is there any other way?

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana It will create a new object TDUtility, if you have already created an object TDUtility that you want to use ( and lets say you named it 'my_TD_obj'), you can call the method enable_logons using 
    my_TD_object.enable_logons("enable_logs3")